# Combining 2 complex Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, function, big-o

Hello I have 2 complex functions that gives values to a Graph component but with 2 different data source.

This is the first Function that handle for 1 graph

```
const timeLine = (data: any, day: string) => {
// subtract 1 hour from the dates here since the chart day columns begin at the 23hr mark
const chartStartDate = moment(activeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').subtract(1, 'hour');
const dayStart: any = moment(day, 'MMM D').subtract(1, 'hour');
let nextDay = moment(dayStart);
nextDay = nextDay.add(1, 'day');
const finalDayData: any[] = [];
(data || []).forEach((activity: any, index: number) => {
  const offSetY = index;
  const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss';
  const startMoment: any = moment(activity['START_DATE'], format);
  const endMoment = moment(activity['END_DATE'], format);
  if (
    (startMoment.isSameOrAfter(dayStart) &&
      startMoment.isBefore(nextDay)) ||
    (startMoment.isBefore(chartStartDate) &&
      dayStart.isSame(chartStartDate, 'day'))
  ) {
    let numberOfUnits;
    let offSetX;
    if (startMoment.isBefore(chartStartDate)) {
      // This bar starts before the start date of the entire chart, so we need to reduce the units so it doesn't overflow to the left.
      numberOfUnits = endMoment.diff(chartStartDate, 'hours', true);
      offSetX = 0;
    } else {
      numberOfUnits = endMoment.diff(startMoment, 'hours', true);
      offSetX = startMoment.diff(dayStart, 'hours', true);
    }
    finalDayData.push({
      numberOfUnits,
      offSetX,
      offSetY,
      unitColor: getUnitColor(activity.UNIT, userPlant)
    });
  }
});
return finalDayData;
};
```

This is the second function that is very similar to the first one but handles for a different dataset.

```
const fireRiskTimeLine = (data: any, day: string) => {
const activityTypes: string[] = [];
// subtract 1 hour from the dates here since the chart day columns begin at the 23hr mark
const chartStartDate = moment(activeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').subtract(1, 'hour');
const dayStart: any = moment(day, 'MMM D').subtract(1, 'hour');
let nextDay = moment(dayStart);
nextDay = nextDay.add(1, 'day');
const finalDayData: any[] = [];
(data || []).forEach((activity: any) => {
  const foundIdx = activityTypes.findIndex(
    (type: string) => activity.DESCRIPTION === type
  );
  if (foundIdx === -1) {
    activityTypes.push(activity.DESCRIPTION);
  }
  const offSetY = foundIdx === -1 ? activityTypes.length - 1 : foundIdx;
  const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss';
  const startMoment: any = moment(activity['BEGIN DATE'], format);
  const endMoment = moment(activity['END DATE'], format);
  if (
    (startMoment.isSameOrAfter(dayStart) &&
      startMoment.isBefore(nextDay)) ||
    (startMoment.isBefore(chartStartDate) &&
      dayStart.isSame(chartStartDate, 'day'))
  ) {
    let numberOfUnits;
    let offSetX;
    if (startMoment.isBefore(chartStartDate)) {
      // This bar starts before the start date of the entire chart, so we need to reduce the units so it doesn't overflow to the left.
      numberOfUnits = endMoment.diff(chartStartDate, 'hours', true);
      offSetX = 0;
    } else {
      numberOfUnits = endMoment.diff(startMoment, 'hours', true);
      offSetX = startMoment.diff(dayStart, 'hours', true);
    }
    finalDayData.push({
      numberOfUnits,
      offSetX,
      offSetY,
      riskColor: activity['COLOR DESCRIPTION']
    });
  }
});
return finalDayData;
};
```

Would there be elegant way to combine these 2 functions or would it better be go ahead and leave as 2 separate functions. I tried to combine them but felt like I was over complicating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite opinion-based, but if both functions do similar things, and you don't need to be able to call them separately, merging them into one seems like it would be a good idea as it would keep your code cleaner.

Comment: Combined function with parameters or a switch block would suffice. Imo

Comment: @JoelHager This is what I'm thinking it it hard with the complexity

Comment: It depends on your use case. If it's the same function just using different data sets, then it should be a less brittle single function. If it's doing complex validation etc. with each data set where the structure is completely different, then it would make sense to keep them separate.  You could even write a wrapper function that resolves all Promises to ensure both are coming through, and you can handle the errors there. Basically it's ideal to make a function do a single thing. Keep it decoupled, and flexible.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it different,

instead of combining I would split it with more functions eg.

```
main(data){
 let data = prepareData(data);
 let combineData = loopData(data);
 return combineData;
}
```

Break down

```
prepareData(data){

const chartStartDate = moment(activeDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').subtract(1, 'hour');
const dayStart: any = moment(day, 'MMM D').subtract(1, 'hour');
let nextDay = moment(dayStart);
nextDay = nextDay.add(1, 'day');
const finalDayData: any[] = [];
}
loopData(data){
(data || []).forEach((activity: any) => {
  const foundIdx = activityTypes.findIndex(
    (type: string) => activity.DESCRIPTION === type
  );
  if (foundIdx === -1) {
    activityTypes.push(activity.DESCRIPTION);
  }
  const offSetY = foundIdx === -1 ? activityTypes.length - 1 : foundIdx;
  const format = 'YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss';
  const startMoment: any = moment(activity['BEGIN DATE'], format);
  const endMoment = moment(activity['END DATE'], format);
  if (
    (startMoment.isSameOrAfter(dayStart) &&
      startMoment.isBefore(nextDay)) ||
    (startMoment.isBefore(chartStartDate) &&
      dayStart.isSame(chartStartDate, 'day'))
  ) {
    let numberOfUnits;
    let offSetX;
    if (startMoment.isBefore(chartStartDate)) {
      // This bar starts before the start date of the entire chart, so we need to reduce the units so it doesn't overflow to the left.
      numberOfUnits = endMoment.diff(chartStartDate, 'hours', true);
      offSetX = 0;
    } else {
      numberOfUnits = endMoment.diff(startMoment, 'hours', true);
      offSetX = startMoment.diff(dayStart, 'hours', true);
    }
    finalDayData.push({
      numberOfUnits,
      offSetX,
      offSetY,
      riskColor: activity['COLOR DESCRIPTION']
    });
  }
```

Code is abstract but I would split it in small functions because if I need new data source tomorrow I would modify only `prepareData()` and not whole thing. my 2 cents :)
}